# JS WebdriverIO TypeError: browser.getMetrics is not a function

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to reproduce an example site https://webdriver.io/docs/devtools-service, but i get an error "TypeError: browser.getMetrics is not a function"

```
const assert = require('assert')

describe('JSON.org page', () => {
    before(() => {
        browser.enablePerformanceAudits()
    })

    it('should load within performance budget', () => {
        /**
         * this page load will take a bit longer as the DevTools service will
         * capture all metrics in the background
         */
        browser.url('http://json.org')

        let metrics = browser.getMetrics()
        assert.ok(metrics.speedIndex < 1500) // check that speedIndex is below 1.5ms

        let score = browser.getPerformanceScore() // get Lighthouse Performance score
        assert.ok(score >= .99) // Lighthouse Performance score is at 99% or higher

        $('=Esperanto').click()

        metrics = browser.getMetrics()
        assert.ok(metrics.speedIndex < 1500)
        score = browser.getPerformanceScore()
        assert.ok(score >= .99)
    })

    after(() => {
        browser.disablePerformanceAudits()
    })
})
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "devtools",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "wdio"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^7.20.7",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.20.7",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.20.7",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.20.7",
    "chromedriver": "^103.0.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

My wdio.conf.js file:

services: ['chromedriver','devtools'],

but i get an error in Terminal:

```
[0-0] TypeError in "JSON.org page.should load within performance budget"
TypeError: browser.getMetrics is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\DevTools\test\specs\1.js:15:31)
    at Context.executeAsync (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\DevTools\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:333:27)
    at Context.testFrameworkFnWrapper (C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\DevTools\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\test-framework\testFnWrapper.js:51:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in asynchronous mode, did this:

```
const assert = require('assert')

describe('JSON.org page', async () => {
    before(() => {
        browser.enablePerformanceAudits()
    })

    it('should load within performance budget', async () => {
        /**
         * this page load will take a bit longer as the DevTools service will
         * capture all metrics in the background
         */
        await browser.url('http://json.org')

        let metrics = browser.getMetrics()
        assert.ok((await metrics).speedIndex < 1500) // check that speedIndex is below 1.5ms

        let score = await browser.getPerformanceScore() // get Lighthouse Performance score
        assert.ok(score >= .90) // Lighthouse Performance score is at 99% or higher
    })

    after(async () => {
        await browser.disablePerformanceAudits()
    })
})
```